# Is there a "do-for" loop in java?

Tags: java, function, loops, for-loop, syntax

I was wondering if there is a for loop that checks the condition after the code block is executed, rather than before. What I'm looking for is something similar to a do-while loop. Does this syntax/function exist?

(Yes I am aware that I can just write parameters elsewhere and use a do-while loop, I'm just curious.)

Comment: No, that does not exist.

Comment: You can see a list of all the statements that do exist in [Chapter 14. Blocks and Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html) of the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Comment: @Joni having written the answer, why delete it? :)

Comment: @Joni Because I don't think it's a useful question/answer. You go ahead an undelete your answer if you want, I'm not going to write one.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not exist. What would be the point?

Consider

```
do {
  ...
} for (int j=0; j<2; j++);
```

1. `j` is not available inside the loop body
2. The loop condition says loop twice, but the loop will execute 3 times.

We can address the first point:

```
int j = 0;
do {
  ...
} for (; j<2; j++);
```

but the `for` loop is already emasculated. It still suffers from obscuring the number of times the loop runs.  At this point you're better off with

```
int j = 0;
do {
  …
  j++;
} while (j<2); // or 3, depending on what you want
```

or even

```
int j = 0;
do {
  …
} while (++j<2);
```